# Javascript onload function of the page which is included is not executed?

Tags: javascript, jsp

There are 2 pages
Page 1 has page 2 included but when page 1 is loaded page 2's onload is not executing.

Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your JavaScript inline or in external .js file? If its inline it will only be executed on that page and should be moved to an external file. You can then reference the file on both pages with a `<script src="yourfile.js"></script>` tag